# how to create several autocomplete fields with html5 and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, autocomplete

I want to create a simple html input page to enter data into mysql db for later use. In order to save time on input I would like to have some fields as autocomplete fields.
I found a script [here](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/08/autocomplete-textbox-html5-datalist-php-mysql-example.html) and after adjusting some values it looks like this

```
<?php
//connect to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","autocomplete_test")
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch data from database
$sql = "select distinct First_Name from data";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Autocomplete Textbox in HTML5 PHP and MySQL</title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" list="firstname" autocomplete="off" id="fname">
<datalist id="firstname">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['First_Name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['First_Name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works great for one field but when I try to add a second field I cannot figure out how to make the second field autocomplete too. In my example I want a second field for 'Last_Name'. It's in the database and I can call all values for First_Name and Last_Name with while and echo as a simple display of what's there before the html part. 
Whatever I try I get autocomplete for first field or for second field or just the first entry from db for both fields. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you tried for `Last_Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from simply querying the database twice, and outputting two inputs:

```
<?php
//connect to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","autocomplete_test")
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch data from database
$sql1 = "select distinct First_Name from data";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql2 = "select distinct Last_Name from data";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Autocomplete Textbox in HTML5 PHP and MySQL</title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" list="firstname" autocomplete="off" id="fname">
<datalist id="firstname">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['First_Name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['First_Name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<label for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" list="lastname" autocomplete="off" id="lname">
<datalist id="lastname">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['Last_Name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Last_Name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unbelievable, I actually had it exactly this way (one of the many attempts ) but I didn't change the variable for $result2 to $sql2 but used $sql1 instead. No wonder I didn't get anything